# Latex not rendering regardless of browser

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

As the title says the math formatting doesn't show regardless of the browser or device I'm using. However changing the network with Vpn or mobile network solves the problem for some browsers so I the only cause I can think of is that it's some problem with my new router (However my network provider is the same as before). The router is an ASUS 750 dual band. Is it really possible that this is the problem and if so, how do I fix it?

Edit: Restarting the router solved the problem, surprisingly. But still, how can the router be the cause of this?